# tlmgr requirement file

Tags: installing, tlmgr

Is there a way to dump the list of installed package to be used as a basis for a new installation with `tlmgr` ? The same way `pip` works:

```
pip freeze > requirements.txt
```

then later, after a fresh `git clone`

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

Comment: See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13939038/how-do-you-run-a-command-for-each-line-of-a-file on how to run `tlmgr` on each line of the package list file, which will install all packages on a new system. Alternatively, `tlmgr` accepts multiple packages as arguments, so you can also write something yourself that generates a command like `tlmgr install package_1 package_2 ... package_n` and run that.

Comment: Yes that's my current solution, but I'd rather avoid using a custom shell script for that if `tlmgr` knew how to do it.